# Send email with hyperlink having a port address

Tags: c#, html

I have a code to send email from C# app. 
Email body has some notes followed by a hyper link.

Ex: If i have the below code, email gets delivered fine

```
<a href=\"http://test.com/demo\">Click</a>
```

But when i replace hyperlink address with a port number 85, the email doesn't get sent. There is no exceptions though.

```
<a href=\"http://test.com:85/demo\">Click</a>
```

How to reference a site with a port number in href when sending an email

Note : Email body is in HTML format.

Comment: Doesn't get sent, or doesn't arrive? If the latter, the SMTP provider is probably blocking emails with suspicious links.

Comment: @spender - doesn't arrive

Comment: Contact your supplier (or use a url shortening service)...

Comment: i did not understand

Comment: It looks like the SMTP server is refusing to send emails with suspicious links, or your inbox provider is blocking them. If you used a URL shortening service such as `https://goo.gl/`, they might slip through the filter.

Comment: I think @spender meant provider, as in e-mail provider. Meaning whoever/whatever company is responsible for routing & delivering the e-mails your code generates.

Comment: @spender - thanks for the answer. you were right. inbox provider is blocking it.